gradle build issue in lady bug iam jusing java 17 and new version of flutter and error
error in gradle build in ladybug asking for agp compatibality
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared_preferences_android:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\scs.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\scs.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}


First of all to make sure that your gradle version is compatible with others, open the "android" file of your flutter project with "Android Studio" and wait till the gradle build. If there is any conflict, you can see the result in the build section and resolve them first.

The error is somehow related to the new AndroidStudio update.Checkout this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/156304
To solve the problem checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79095064/7369590

Update: Gradle version:8.3 android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip
Update: Java version: 20
Notice: When you change project Gradle version and run application, then Java Compatibility version automatically download for this project. Don't worry.
Use latest Gradle & java version in your project make great impact of your apps performance.

